# How to keep track of multiple matches in drools

Tags: drools, rules, rule-engine

I have a rule that fires many times for products that match my product code. How do I get all the products that have been matched? I know I can use a global and a set, but is there another way?

```
 global Set set

rule "match multiple products"
  when $prod: Product(code=='PRD-MERCH') from productList
  then
  System.out.println('Matched Products');
  set.add($prod); 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let me tell you that the `from productList` you are using already looks suspicious. Is `productList` a global?

Now, going back to your question, if you are interested in all the `Product` facts that match, you can use a `collect` pattern:

```
rule "match multiple products"
when 
  $prods: List(size > 0) from collect (
    Product(code=='PRD-MERCH') from productList
  )
then
  System.out.println("Matched Products"+ $prods); 
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you Esteban. Yes productList is a global